# Javascript string syntax to write SQL

Tags: javascript, string, query-string

I am writing an SQL query as a Javascript string like that:

```
  SQLdetail =  'SELECT [Avis SAP], Avis.[Ordre SAP], [Date Appel], [Heur Appel], Client_List![Code Client], [Numero Passerelle], [Designation Appel], Ordre![Metier], Ordre!Repercussion, Ordre!Objet, Ordre![Profil Panne], Ordre!Cause, Ordre![Sommaire Correctif], Ordre![Statut]'
  SQLdetail += ' FROM (Avis' 
  SQLdetail += ' LEFT JOIN Client_List ON Avis.[Numero Client] = Client_List.[Numero Client])' 
  SQLdetail += ' LEFT JOIN Ordre ON Avis.[Ordre SAP] = Ordre.[Ordre SAP] WHERE Avis.[Date Appel] BETWEEN #' & DateOne & '# AND #' & DateTwo & '#;' 
  alert('SQLdetail:' + SQLdetail)
```

and the last `SQLdetail +=` somehow returns "0". Am I missing something in the syntax that just turns the whole string to a 0?

Comment: What is in variables DateOne and DateTwo?  Is it a string?  If not you many want to convert to a string.

Comment: I hope you won't be using JS to generate SQL which is sent to a server to be executed, otherwise I hope you'll enjoy mean users hacking the script to send `DROP DATABASE database();`

Comment: Why are you constructing SQL with javascript? This should be done server side.

Comment: I have a question! What do you want to do with your `SQL` in **JavaScript**?

Comment: ok ppl relax, its an internal web app I have no choice but to use client side and access 2003...

Comment: I think an explanation is needed.  If this is Serverside Javascript, then so be it, but if it is client side I will flag this as a really bad question so it can be removed.  We don't need any spiders finding this solution when someone types "SQL and javascript"

Comment: @Zoidberg: I doubt the question will be removed. It's valid and people have voiced their concerns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing with **VB syntax**. In JavaScript you must concatenate string with `+`

```
SQLdetail += ' LEFT JOIN Ordre ON Avis.[Ordre SAP] = Ordre.[Ordre SAP] WHERE Avis.[Date Appel] BETWEEN #' + DateOne + '# AND #' + DateTwo + '#;'
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using a bitwise operator in your code:

```
& DateTwo &
```

This doesn't join strings. Use a `+`:

```
+ DateTwo +
```

---

Other than that, *why in the world are you generating your SQL with JavaScript*???

The only way you can send it to your server is through the browser, which means that *I have total control over the request*.

Basically, you are giving me root privileges to your database. I'm nice and won't abuse it, but I can only speak for myself.

Answer (score 2):

What are with the `&`? : `BETWEEN #' & DateOne & '# AND #' & DateTwo & '#;'`

Change to a `+`

Answer (score 2):

If this is Javascript you need to use + instead of & here:

```
SQLdetail += ' LEFT JOIN Ordre ON Avis.[Ordre SAP] = Ordre.[Ordre SAP] WHERE Avis.[Date Appel] BETWEEN #' & DateOne & '# AND #' & DateTwo & '#;'
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `&` to concatenate instead of `+`